# Why does btsync core dump with "!directory.empty()" error when started?

Tags: synchronization

When I start BitTorrent Sync (`btsync` x64 build) 1.4.110 on a fresh install of Fedora 21, using a configuration file known to work on a different system, I get this perplexing error message:

```
$ btsync --config /home/user/.btsync.conf
btsync: /mnt/jenkins/workspace/Build-Sync-x64/linux/breakpad/client/linux/handler/minidump_descriptor.h:55: google_breakpad::MinidumpDescriptor::MinidumpDescriptor(const string&): Assertion `!directory.empty()' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I don't have Jenkins installed on this system. It looks like the BitTorrent Sync build compiled with symbols from the BitTorrent organisation's release engineering build server environment. Heh.

What is the problem? Here is my configuration file from `/home/user/.btsync.conf`:

```
{
  "device_name": "MyLaptop",
  "listening_port" : 0, // 0 - randomize port

/* storage_path dir contains auxilliary app files if no storage_path field: .sync dir created in the directory
   where binary is located. otherwise user-defined directory will be used */
 "storage_path" : "/home/user/.btsync",

/* set location of pid file */
 "pid_file" : "/var/run/btsync/btsync.pid",

/* use UPnP for port mapping */
  "use_upnp" : true,

/* limits in kB/s. 0 - no limit */
  "download_limit" : 0,
  "upload_limit" : 0,

/* proxy configuration */
// "proxy_type" : "socks4", // Valid types: "socks4", "socks5", "http_connect". Any other value means no proxy
// "proxy_addr" : "192.168.1.2", // IP address of proxy server.
// "proxy_port" : 1080,
// "proxy_auth" : false, // Use authentication for proxy. Note: only username/password for socks5 (RFC 1929) is supported, and it is not really secure
// "proxy_username" : "user",
// "proxy_password" : "password",

  "webui" :
  {
//    "listen" : "0.0.0.0:8888" // remove field to disable WebUI

/* preset credentials. Use password or password_hash */
//  ,"login" : "admin"
//  ,"password" : "password"
//  ,"password_hash" : "some_hash" // password hash in crypt(3) format
//  ,"allow_empty_password" : false // Defaults to true
/* ssl configuration */
//  ,"force_https" : true // disable http
//  ,"ssl_certificate" : "/path/to/cert.pem"
//  ,"ssl_private_key" : "/path/to/private.key"

/* directory_root path defines where the WebUI Folder browser starts (linux only). Default value is / */
//  ,"directory_root" : "/home/user/MySharedFolders/"

/* dir_whitelist defines which directories can be shown to user or have folders added (linux only)
   relative paths are relative to directory_root setting */
//  ,"dir_whitelist" : [ "/home/user/MySharedFolders/personal", "work" ]
  }

/* !!! if you set shared folders in config file WebUI will be DISABLED !!!
   shared directories specified in config file  override the folders previously added from WebUI. */
,
  "shared_folders" :
  [
    {
      "secret" : "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA", // required field - use --generate-secret in command line to create new secret
      "dir" : "/home/user/SyncFolder1", // * required field
      "use_relay_server" : true, //  use relay server when direct connection fails
      "use_tracker" : true,
      "use_dht" : false,
      "search_lan" : true,
      "use_sync_trash" : true, // enable SyncArchive to store files deleted on remote devices
      "overwrite_changes" : false, // restore modified files to original version, ONLY for Read-Only folders
      "known_hosts" : // specify hosts to attempt connection without additional search
      [
        "192.168.0.201:8888"
      ]
    },
    {
      "secret" : "BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB", // required field - use --generate-secret in command line to create new secret
      "dir" : "/home/user/SyncFolder2", // * required field
      "use_relay_server" : true, //  use relay server when direct connection fails
      "use_tracker" : true,
      "use_dht" : false,
      "search_lan" : true,
      "use_sync_trash" : true, // enable SyncArchive to store files deleted on remote devices
      "overwrite_changes" : false, // restore modified files to original version, ONLY for Read-Only folders
      "known_hosts" : // specify hosts to attempt connection without additional search
      [
        "192.168.0.201:8888"
      ]
    }
  ]


/* Advanced preferences can be added to config file. Info is available at http://sync-help.bittorrent.com */

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem turned out to be the configuration of the following folders:

- `/home/user/.btsync` -- the folder to hold BitTorrent Sync meta-data
- `/home/user/SyncFolder1` -- a folder to sync
- `/home/user/SyncFolder2` -- a folder to sync

When `btsync` started, the meta-data folder `/home/user/.btsync` did not exist. I created it, and made sure that it was writable by my user account. I also created both sync folders. After these folders were created, `btsync` started normally:

```
$ btsync --config /home/user/.btsync.conf
By using this application, you agree to our Privacy Policy, Terms of Use and End User License Agreement.
http://www.bittorrent.com/legal/privacy
http://www.bittorrent.com/legal/terms-of-use
http://www.bittorrent.com/legal/eula

BitTorrent Sync forked to background. pid = 15949. default port = 8888
```